# How to make CompletableFuture exceptonally function returns Collection type?

Tags: java, generics, completable-future

The project that I work on have some code that can be simplified as the following two functions:

```
CompletionStage<Collection<String>> fn1(String prefix) {
  return fn2()
      .thenApply(list -> list.stream()
          .map(s -> prefix + s)
          .collect(Collectors.toList())
      );
}

CompletionStage<List<String>> fn2() {
  return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(List.of("results", "of", "computation"));
}
```

It works well. However, `fn1` cannot compile after adding an `exceptionally` step:

```
CompletionStage<Collection<String>> fn1(String prefix) {
  return fn2()
      .thenApply(list -> list.stream()
          .map(s -> prefix + s)
          .collect(Collectors.toList())
      ).exceptionally(t -> {
        // Log the error
        // ...

        // return an empty collection
        Collection<String> emptyCol = List.of();
        return emptyCol;  // Error: Collection<String> cannot be converted to List<String>

        // Also tried the following two ways
        // List<String> emptyList = List.of();
        // return emptyList;   // Error: CompletionStage<List<String>> cannot be converted to CompletionStage<Collection<String>>
        // return emptyList.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()); // Error same as above
      });
}
```

How to fix it, supposing that we cannot change the signature of `fn1`? Why `.collect(Collectors.toList())` is fine for `thenApply`?

BTW, the JDK is 11.

Comment: Please share the full error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exceptionally` must return the same type as the original future. Since the generic type of your return type is `Collection<String>`, you must help the Java compiler figure out that your future really returns a `Collection` and not a `List`.

All options to fix this issue are trivial: type witness, cast, or temporary variable.

Type witness:

```
CompletionStage<Collection<String>> fn1(String prefix) {
    return fn2()
            .<Collection<String>>thenApply(list -> list.stream()
                    .map(s -> prefix + s)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            ).exceptionally(t -> Collections.emptyList());
}
```

Cast:

```
CompletionStage<Collection<String>> fn1(String prefix) {
    return fn2()
            .thenApply(list -> (Collection<String>)list.stream()
                    .map(s -> prefix + s)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            ).exceptionally(t -> Collections.emptyList());
}
```

Variable:

```
CompletionStage<Collection<String>> fn1(String prefix) {
    final CompletionStage<Collection<String>> stage = fn2()
            .thenApply(list -> list.stream()
                    .map(s -> prefix + s)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return stage.exceptionally(t -> Collections.emptyList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a few more options to the answer from @knittl :

The compiler doesn't assume that a `CompletionStage<List<String>>` is  "similar enough" to a `CompletionStage<Collection<String>>`, so you cannot return the form with the `List` type parameter in place of the form with the `Collection` type parameter.

If you would be able to change the signature of `fn1` in this way, your problem would have been gone:

```
CompletionStage<? extends Collection<String>> fn1(String prefix) {
  return fn2()
      .thenApply(list1 -> list1.stream()
          .map(s1 -> prefix + s1)
          .collect(Collectors.toList()))
      .exceptionally(t -> List.of());
}
```

In that case you would not even need the mapping you do inside the `thenApply` right now, if you do it mainly for the type conversion.

Or if your exception handling is not for the mapping but for the call to `fn2()`, you could simply flip the exception handling and the mapping in order:

```
CompletionStage<Collection<String>> fn1(String prefix) {
  return fn2()
      .exceptionally(t -> List.of())
      .thenApply(list -> list.stream()
          .map(s -> prefix + s)
          .collect(Collectors.toList())
      );
}
```

Or if you need that mapping and the exception handling in that order, you could apply another "mapping" at the end:

```
CompletionStage<Collection<String>> fn1(String prefix) {
  return fn2()
      .thenApply(list1 -> list1.stream()
          .map(s1 -> prefix + s1)
          .collect(Collectors.toList()))
      .exceptionally(t -> List.of())
      .thenApply(Function.identity());
}
```

(In this case the second "mapping" really doesn't do much except convince the compiler to accept a `List<String>` as a `Collection<String>` by another call to a standard function that returns it's input without further processing.)

Comment: Great answer. I just want to mention that returning wildcard types can cause other issues: you get a type, but don't know what type.

Comment: @knittl: Actually, returning a `CompletionStage` with an `extends` wildcard is almost always a good idea, because of the PECS (producer `extends`, consumer `super`) rule -- here, the caller would only get the collection out of the `CompletionStage`, and the caller would generally never try to put a new value into the `CompletionStage` since that is the job of the chained futures inside this method, so the `CompletionStage` is a producer with respect to the caller.

Comment: @cyberbrain: "The compiler doesn't assume that a CompletionStage<List<String>> is "similar enough" to a CompletionStage<Collection<String>>, so you cannot return the form with the List type parameter in place of the form with the Collection type parameter." Or, put more succinctly: generics type arguments are invariant. `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`, or vice versa, even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`.

Comment: @newacct Thanks for this precise clarification! I wanted to write it like this in the first attempt, but then decided to find words that are hopefully easier to understand for the level of knowledge that I deducted from the question.